# Find maximum date records for all USER_IDs of a group

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `emp_attendance` in which two columns are there `log_in_date` and `user_id`.

I just want to fetch all `maximum ( latest ) log_in dates` for all given user_ids ( more than 100 user_ids are given ). Means, I just want to know on which latest ( maximum ) date, a particular user had logged on.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
SELECT user_id,log_in_date FROM emp_attendance where log_in_date = (select max(log_in_date) from emp_attendance where user_id in (28,112,
160,244,276,284);
```

But I am getting same log_in_date for all user_ids. Where am I going wrong?

Note: There are so many USER_IDs given, I have provided only six USER_IDs here as a sample.

Comment: why not use `group by` and `order by`

Comment: I am not so much aware with group by , Can you please help me out with that how to use that ?

Comment: see @nos's answer. already answered what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty straight forward:

```
SELECT user_id,max(log_in_date) FROM emp_attendance GROUP BY user_id;
```

And if you only wanted that for a subset of your user ids:

```
SELECT user_id,max(log_in_date) FROM emp_attendance WHERE
       user_id in (28,112,160,244,276,284) GROUP BY user_id;
```